# Complex sequence based on a condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to transform data into data2. I am looking for a base R or dplyr solution.
There is an ID associated with each policy. There is a start date and an end date. These are all given.
A policy year starts on the start date and ends one year later. A policy may go for several years. The first part of a policy needs to have a PolYr value of 0. When the policy year goes into the next year, PolYr takes the value 1.  I was able to figure that out via

[Numeric sequence with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32965823/numeric-sequence-with-condition)

For each contract, there is a row for each PolYr and CaldYr combination. I also need to determine the CaldYr.
Looking at ID = 103, we see that the contract starts in 2011, its first row will have PolYr = 0 and CaldYr = 2011. The second part of PolYr 0 goes into 2012 so the second row for ID = 103 will have PolYr = 1 and CaldYr = 2012. This policy is more than 2 years in length and finishes in late 2013 so it goes for five rows.

Below are before and after data frames.
I did some research, but did not find anything that I perceived as corresponding to my problem.

```
library(dplyr)    
ID = c(101, rep(102, 2), rep(103,5))
    start = as.Date(c('2/1/2010', rep('5/17/2011', 2), rep('5/17/2011', 5)), '%m/%d/%Y')
    end = as.Date(c('3/5/2010', rep('1/4/2012', 2 ), rep('8/4/2013', 5 )), '%m/%d/%Y')
    data = data.frame(ID = ID, start = start, end = end)

    v = c(0,1)
    data = data %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(PolYr = rep_len(v, length(ID)))
    data

    data2 = data
    data2$CaldrYr = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013)
    data2
```

Comment: I don't think you've laid out your logic sufficiently to show what needs to happen, but you could reproduce `data2` with `data %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(CaldrYr = lubridate::year(start) + cumsum(PolYr))`. Maybe that's what you're after?

Comment: Yes. That solves my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `data.table`, we can do

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
setDT(data)[, CaldrYr := year(start) + cumsum(PolYr), ID]
```

Comment: @user2738483  it could be either releated to the `year` extraction or `cumsum` but cumsum is faster option.  Perhaps change the `year(start)` to `as.integer(substr(start, 1, 4))`

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I timed the three methods data.table was the fastest. Then base R. Then dplyr.
I used system.time
data.table: 3.20 sec
base R: 5.97
dplyr: 9.24 

I am working with over 2 million rows and hundreds of thousands of ID (= ContractKey)
The real bottleneck turns out to be
 
system.time(data_res2 <- data_res2 %>% group_by(ContractKey) %>% mutate(PolYr = rep_len(c(0,1), length(ContractKey))))

# user  system elapsed 
# 924.16  673.19 1598.32
Is there a faster data.table solution?

Comment: @user2738483 ii think the `substr` method is slower compared to the 'year'.  From my experiments with `8e6` data, the original version is the fastest.  May be , it is the cumsum that is the issue here

Comment: The first method was much faster
system.time(setDT(data_res2)[, CaldrYr2 := year(SALE_DATE) + cumsum(PolYr), ContractKey])
# user  system elapsed 
# 3.17    0.06    3.20

system.time(setDT(data_res2)[, PolYrcum := cumsum(PolYr), ContractKey
            ][, CaldrYr2c := as.integer(substr(SALE_DATE, 1, 4)) + PolYrcum
              ][, PolYrcum := NULL][])
# user  system elapsed 
# 11.27    0.33   11.53

Answer (score 1):

In base R, we can use `ave` to get `cumsum` by group and add the `year` value of `start`.

```
data$CaldrYr <- with(data, as.integer(format(start, "%Y")) + 
                            ave(PolYr, ID, FUN = cumsum))

#     ID  start      end        PolYr CaldrYr
#  <dbl> <date>     <date>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#1   101 2010-02-01 2010-03-05     0    2010
#2   102 2011-05-17 2012-01-04     0    2011
#3   102 2011-05-17 2012-01-04     1    2012
#4   103 2011-05-17 2013-08-04     0    2011
#5   103 2011-05-17 2013-08-04     1    2012
#6   103 2011-05-17 2013-08-04     0    2012
#7   103 2011-05-17 2013-08-04     1    2013
#8   103 2011-05-17 2013-08-04     0    2013
```