# Numeric sequence with a condition (continued). A data.table solution?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Yesterday I asked a question.
[Complex sequence based on a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61706936/complex-sequence-based-on-a-condition?noredirect=1#comment109150075_61706936)

Thank you to those who helped me solve it.
My minimal example was

```
library(dplyr)    
ID = c(101, rep(102, 2), rep(103,5))
    start = as.Date(c('2/1/2010', rep('5/17/2011', 2), rep('5/17/2011', 5)), '%m/%d/%Y')
    end = as.Date(c('3/5/2010', rep('1/4/2012', 2 ), rep('8/4/2013', 5 )), '%m/%d/%Y')
    data = data.frame(ID = ID, start = start, end = end)

    v = c(0,1)
    data = data %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(PolYr = rep_len(v, length(ID)))
    data
```

Now I am hoping someone can help me with this part of the code.

```
v = c(0,1)
data = data %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(PolYr = rep_len(v, length(ID)))
```

The code runs. However, on my real data with more than 2 million rows of data and hundreds of thousands of ID, the elapsed time was 2297.74.
I am hoping someone can suggest a faster method, perhaps with data.table, which I am just trying to learn.
The goal is for each ID to start PolYr with a 0 and then continue with a 1 (if there is a second row) and then back to 0, 1, …

Comment: Can you change it to `n()` `mutate(PolYr = rep_len(v, n()))`

Comment: `setDT(data)[,  PolYr := rep_len(v, .N), .ID]` in `data.table`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `data.table`, we can use `.N` in `rep_len` and assign (`:=`) to create the new column after grouping by ID

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, PolYr := rep_len(v, .N), by = ID]
```

Comment: Thanks. The data.table and dplyr methods produced the same result.
I started with a tibble with 2,395,812 rows and 417,438 values for the grouping variable.
Using system.time() data.table took elapsed time of 0.39 seconds;  and dplyr took elapsed time of 1862.56 seconds. The alternate method suggested by @Akrun reduced the time to 2.31 seconds.
The data.table solution really helps because the code needs to be run on over 20 datasets.

Comment: you meant `length` is taking less time than `.N`?

Comment: To clarify.
data.table 0.39 seconds; 
dplyr  with length 1862.56 seconds; 
dplyr with n() 2.31 seconds